# unable to map webdav server drive to windows 10

Tags: networking, windows-10, webdav

I have **WINDOWS 10 HOME SINGLE LANGUAGE** os on my laptop.
I am trying to map my android mobile's drive shared using **WEBDAV SERVER**
I have started webdav server in android mobile.
When I am mapping it in my windows 10 home laptop it is giving error.

It was working fine before windows latest update.

**This problem is occuring since windows latest update version: 1709,  OS Build: 16299.192**

I have wasted 10 days googling this issue.But not getting solution yet.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error does it give? Is there any specific information in Event Viewer?

Comment: here is screenshot

Comment: http://www.ktronsystem.com/a.png